# iOS, Instabug view dismissal callback?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, instabug

I have a game that uses the Instabug feedback form.  I pause the game when they press the feedback button, then display the form.  However, I'm having trouble determining when the user is finished interacting with the form.  I don't believe that there is a callback available with the Instabug SDK.

I there a way to tell somehow using iOS view callbacks / hierarchy?  I'm not sure exactly how the feedback form works, but it shows an overlay like this.

[image: Feedback Form]